# Issue with connecting points for 3d line plot in plotly

Tags: python, r, plotly, data-visualization

I have a dataframe of the following format:

```
       x    y    z aa_num frame_num cluster
1   1.86 3.11 8.62      1         1       1
2   1.77 3.32 8.31      2         1       1
3   1.59 3.17 8.00      3         1       1
4   1.67 3.49 7.81      4         1       1
5   2.04 3.59 7.81      5         1       1
6   2.20 3.34 7.57      6         1       1
7   2.09 3.19 7.25      7         1       1
8   2.13 3.30 6.89      8         1       1
9   2.17 3.63 6.70      9         1       1
10  2.22 3.63 6.33     10         1       1
11  2.06 3.83 6.04     11         1       1
12  2.31 3.75 5.76     12         1       1
13  2.15 3.45 5.59     13         1       1
14  2.21 3.28 5.26     14         1       1
15  2.00 3.13 4.98     15         1       1
16  2.13 2.86 4.74     16         1       1
17  1.97 2.78 4.41     17         1       1
18  2.20 2.76 4.10     18         1       1
19  2.43 2.46 4.14     19         1       1
20  2.34 2.23 3.85     20         1       1
21  2.61 2.16 3.59     21         1       1
22  2.42 1.92 3.36     22         1       1
23  2.44 1.95 2.98     23         1       1
24  2.26 1.62 2.94     24         1       1
25  2.19 1.35 3.20     25         1       1
26  1.92 1.11 3.08     26         1       1
27  1.93 0.83 3.33     27         1       1
28  1.83 0.72 3.68     28         1       1
29  1.95 0.47 3.95     29         1       1
30  1.84 0.36 4.29     30         1       1
31  0.56 3.93 7.07      1         2       1
32  0.66 3.84 7.42      2         2       1
33  0.87 3.54 7.49      3         2       1
34  0.84 3.19 7.33      4         2       1
35  0.76 3.32 6.98      5         2       1
36  0.88 3.23 6.63      6         2       1
37  1.10 3.46 6.43      7         2       1
38  1.35 3.49 6.15      8         2       1
39  1.72 3.50 6.23      9         2       1
40  1.88 3.67 5.93     10         2       1
41  2.25 3.72 5.97     11         2       1
42  2.43 3.48 5.74     12         2       1
43  2.23 3.35 5.44     13         2       1
44  2.23 3.38 5.06     14         2       1
45  2.01 3.38 4.76     15         2       1
46  2.02 3.44 4.38     16         2       1
47  1.98 3.10 4.20     17         2       1
48  2.05 3.13 3.83     18         2       1
49  2.28 2.85 3.72     19         2       1
50  2.09 2.56 3.58     20         2       1
51  2.21 2.37 3.27     21         2       1
52  2.06 2.04 3.15     22         2       1
53  1.93 2.01 2.80     23         2       1
54  1.86 1.64 2.83     24         2       1
55  1.95 1.38 3.10     25         2       1
56  1.78 1.04 3.04     26         2       1
57  1.90 0.84 3.34     27         2       1
58  1.83 0.74 3.70     28         2       1
59  1.95 0.48 3.95     29         2       1
60  1.84 0.36 4.29     30         2       1
etc..
```

I'm trying to create a 3d line plot of this data, where a line consisting of 30 <x,y,z> points will be plotted for each frame_num and the points would be connected in the order of aa_num. The code to do this is as follows:

```
    fig = plot_ly(output_cl, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers',
                   opacity = 1, line = list(width = 1, color = ~frame_num, colorscale = 'Viridis'),
                  marker = list(size = 2, color = ~frame_num, colorscale = 'Viridis'))
```

When I plot a single frame, it works fine:

[image]

However, a strange issue arises when I try to plot multiple instances.

[image]

For some reason, when I try to plot frame 1 and 2, point 1 and 30 connect to each other for frame 2. However, this doesn't happen for frame 1. Any ideas why? Is there someway to specify the ordering of points in 3d in plotly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create two different traces based on column `frame_num` you need to pass it as a categorial variable by using `factor`. As an alternative you can use `name = ~ frame_num` or `split = ~ frame_num` to create multiple traces.

```
library(plotly)

output_cl <- data.frame(
           x = c(1.86,1.77,1.59,1.67,2.04,2.2,2.09,
                 2.13,2.17,2.22,2.06,2.31,2.15,2.21,2,2.13,1.97,2.2,
                 2.43,2.34,2.61,2.42,2.44,2.26,2.19,1.92,1.93,1.83,1.95,
                 1.84,0.56,0.66,0.87,0.84,0.76,0.88,1.1,1.35,1.72,1.88,
                 2.25,2.43,2.23,2.23,2.01,2.02,1.98,2.05,2.28,2.09,
                 2.21,2.06,1.93,1.86,1.95,1.78,1.9,1.83,1.95,1.84),
           y = c(3.11,3.32,3.17,3.49,3.59,3.34,3.19,
                 3.3,3.63,3.63,3.83,3.75,3.45,3.28,3.13,2.86,2.78,2.76,
                 2.46,2.23,2.16,1.92,1.95,1.62,1.35,1.11,0.83,0.72,
                 0.47,0.36,3.93,3.84,3.54,3.19,3.32,3.23,3.46,3.49,3.5,
                 3.67,3.72,3.48,3.35,3.38,3.38,3.44,3.1,3.13,2.85,2.56,
                 2.37,2.04,2.01,1.64,1.38,1.04,0.84,0.74,0.48,0.36),
           z = c(8.62,8.31,8,7.81,7.81,7.57,7.25,6.89,
                 6.7,6.33,6.04,5.76,5.59,5.26,4.98,4.74,4.41,4.1,
                 4.14,3.85,3.59,3.36,2.98,2.94,3.2,3.08,3.33,3.68,3.95,
                 4.29,7.07,7.42,7.49,7.33,6.98,6.63,6.43,6.15,6.23,5.93,
                 5.97,5.74,5.44,5.06,4.76,4.38,4.2,3.83,3.72,3.58,
                 3.27,3.15,2.8,2.83,3.1,3.04,3.34,3.7,3.95,4.29),
      aa_num = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,
                 11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,19L,20L,21L,22L,23L,
                 24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,29L,30L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,
                 8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,19L,20L,
                 21L,22L,23L,24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,29L,30L),
   frame_num = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                 2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
                 2L,2L),
     cluster = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                 1L,1L)
)

fig = plot_ly(output_cl, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~factor(frame_num), # or name = ~ frame_num or split = ~ frame_num
              colors ="Set2", opacity = 1, line = list(width = 1), marker = list(size = 2))
fig
```

[image: result]